# Clear/Reset Material AngualrJS <md-autocomplete>

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material, md-autocomplete

I want to reset `<md-autocomplete>` control in Material AngularJS.

```
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.autocomplete
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/api/material.components.autocomplete/directive/mdAutocomplete
```

Basically I want to reset it to it's initial state. I can access `ng-model` & assign `null` to it. But, it doesn't remove the displayed text contained in `md-item-text` attribute.

Can please someone let me know how can I solve the same.

Answer (score 5):

You need to clear the search text, have a look at this codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbGZWP?editors=101

I created a button that calls the clear function:

```
function clear() {
  self.selectedItem = null;
  self.searchText = "";
}
```

These are the attributes set on the `md-autocomplete` directive:

```
<md-autocomplete 
  md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem" 
  md-search-text="ctrl.searchText" 
  md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)" 
>
```

Note: You might need the other attributes too, depends on your case.

Comment: your solution works, when clear() is invoked by ng-click.. but it doesn't work when called from inside a function invoked by `md-selected-item-change`

Comment: @Lloyd: Works as expected. Edited the codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOmqwv?editors=101

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vdbpYv?editors=1010 ..md-autocomplete reset is not working

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vdbpYv?editors=1010 ..md-autocomplete reset is not working

Comment: Works amazingly, thank you. Spent a half a day to resolve this, until I've found your answer. Big vote up!

Answer (score 2):

you may use `md-selected-item-change` to handle this.
for example

```
    <md-autocomplete flex
       md-item-text="item.Text"
       md-items="item in data"
       md-search-text-change="query(searchText)"
       md-search-text="searchText"
       md-selected-item="selectedItem"
       md-no-cache="false"
       md-input-minLength="2"
       md-input-name="exampleAutocomplete"
       md-selected-item-change="addSelectedItem();"
       md-floating-label="Nereye">
           <md-item-template>
               <span md-highlight-text="searchText">{{item.Text}}</span>
           </md-item-template>
           <md-not-found>No matching were found were "{{searchText}}".</md-not-found>
    </md-autocomplete>
```

and your controller side, you must define a function with name "addSelectedItem" and assign searchText with an empty string. like;

```
$scope.addSelectedItem = function () {
            $scope.searchText = ''; 
};
```

it works for me. hopefully it will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vdbpYv?editors=1010 ..md-autocomplete reset is not working

Comment: you can try md-clear-button="true" attribute. Both of them work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Set md-min-length="1" would make the clear work without extra clear function or button.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vdbpYv?editors=1010 ..md-autocomplete reset is not working

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vdbpYv?editors=1010 ..md-autocomplete reset is not working